# Create an associative array where the keys match the values

Tags: php, associative-array

What is the best way to create:

```
[
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => 'bar',
]
```

from this array:

```
[
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => 'bar',
]
```

I've looked at *array_map*, *array_walk*, and *array_column*, but I cannot figure out if any of these functions will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Try the following:

```
$input_array = array( 
                      [1] => 'foo',
                      [2] => 'bar'
                    );

// use array_combine such that keys and values are same source
$expected_output = array_combine($input_array, $input_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply using foreach:

```
$array = array(
     'foo',
     'bar'
);
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $val)
{
    $newArray[$val] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Sure you can, but… why?

Comment: If you don't remember what array_combine does, or if you don't remember that function at the precise moment you need it, that's the faster solution :)

Comment: If that is a primary issue you're fighting with, and you are unable to look up the function name in the manual, you'll have a pretty hard time developing anything.

Comment: Ahaha come on, OP asked what is the best to create arrayB from arrayA, I gave a simple solution in PHP, he didn't ask to use any function (even if he said he looked up).

Comment: What if you can remember array_combine but you can't remember foreach?